# EJS file does not recognize <% %> tags

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnSkv.png)I was trying to pass some credentials to my model, but the ejs tags (<%%>), stopped being recognized and are not responding anymore. Does anyone know +/- what could cause this? I'm new to programming, I tried to search for this error, but I didn't find anything :/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please include code and errors as text instead of images, this makes it searchable for other users with similar problems.

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the parts about providing code and error messages as *text*, not as pictures of text and about providing a [mcve] (we don't know how you are trying to execute the EJS).

Comment: 1) is the EJS templating engine actually saying that your code is erring? Or is it just a visual problem with syntax highlighting? 2) what code editor program are you using? VS Code? Are you using any EJS extensions?